# window.location does not pass the complete string

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to pass long string variable to another page (fillDB.php) using window.location

```
window.location = "fillDB.php?encoding_str=" + JSON_encoding_str;
```

but the string does not passed completely to fillDB.php, here is the code in fillDB.php:

```
$encoding_str = json_decode($_REQUEST['encoding_str']);
echo $encoding_str;
```

the string is printed but it is not complete, I do not know where is the problem!

I've assigned value to encoding string:

```
encoding_str += isSimilar_DB(game)+","+reaction[3]+";";
```

then used JSON.stringify:

```
var JSON_encoding_str = JSON.stringify(encoding_str);
```

to make thing clear:

```
isSimilar_DB(game)
```

is a function that returns a long string
and

```
reaction[3]
```

returns an ID

when passing the whole string JSON_encoding_str, reaction[3] is printed correctely but the returned string(isSimilar_DB(game)) is not complete

**EDIT:** I've solved the problem. I thought that the problem is the length of the string or the limit length of the URL, but I found that the problem was that the string returned from isSimilar(game) function contained the less than letter "<", so the string is printed until it reach to "<" and stop, I still do not know the reason but any way I replaced "<" with "=" and it worked fine. Thank you all.

Comment: show the part where you assign value to JSON_encoding_str

Comment: I've assigned value to encoding string:


    encoding_str += isSimilar_DB(game)+","+reaction[3]+";";

then used JSON.stringify: var JSON_encoding_str = JSON.stringify(encoding_str);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a character limit for URL. It's different for different browsers.
Overall, you should not have urls with more than 2000 characters.
You can check this thread: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)
If you are over this limit, your url will be cut.

Comment: I am using firefox and JSON_encoding_string length is about 700 characters

Comment: but window.location is using GET, how to switch to POST using window.location?